# How do I get an error message when failing to load a JVM via JNI?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-arguments

I would like to retrieve an error message that explains why the jvm failed to load. From the examples provided here:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html

I extracted this example:

```
 /* Create the Java VM */
 res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

 if (res < 0) {
     // retrieve verbose error here?
     fprintf(stderr, "Can't create Java VM\n");
     exit(1);
 }
```

In my specific case I'm providing invalid arguments in the vm_args and would expect to see  what I get on the command line: "Unrecognized option: -foo=bar"

On further testing it looks like the jvm is putting the message I want to stdout or stderr. I believe I would need to capture stdout and stderr to get the error I'm looking for (unless of course there is a simpler way). I'm coding in C++ so if someone can show a way to capture the error into a stringstream that would be ideal.

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get what I needed by using the "vfprintf" option described here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20111229234347/http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/jnifaq-old.html

although I used the jdk1.2 options. This code snippet summarizes my solution:

```
static string jniErrors;

static jint JNICALL my_vfprintf(FILE *fp, const char *format, va_list args)
{
    char buf[1024];
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, args);
    jniErrors += buf;
    return 0;
}

...

JavaVMOption options[1];
options[0].optionString = "vfprintf";
options[0].extraInfo = my_vfprintf;

JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

JNIEnv env;
JavaVM jvm;

jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

if (res != JNI_OK)
    setError(jniErrors);

jniErrors.clear();
```

Also interesting was that I could not for the life of me capture stdout or stderr correctly with any of the freopen or dup2 tricks. I could load my *own* dll and redirect correctly but not the jvm. Anyway, it's better this way because I wanted the errors in memory rather than in a file.

Comment: The link to sun.java.com no longer works and the function `setError()` is not declared in the snippet. Any hints about where to find it?

Comment: This looks to be the same link although it's been a long time: [old-faq](http://192.9.162.55/products/jdk/faq/jnifaq-old.html). The setError method was just a helper method we defined. The jniErrors string will include the error message at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Should I update the link in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote this code I would also get the error via stdout/stderr.

The best way to redirect stdout/stderr in your process is by using [freopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html). Here is a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c) specifically about that subject.

However, once that call is passed, you will then have a `JNIEnv`, and all further error checking can and should be done by calling `JNIEnv::ExceptionOccurred()`, which will may return a `Throwable` object that you can then interrogate with your JNI code.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a hold of stdout and stderr, which you'll need anyway, add [-Xcheck:jni](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts002.html) to your jvm command line to get extra jni-related warnings from the jvm.