# JNI_ENOMEM from JNI_CreateJavaVM when calling dll that uses JNI from VB6

Tags: java, memory, vb6, java-native-interface, visio

I work on a legacy system that has a VB6 app that needs to call Java code.  The solution we use is to have the VB app call a C++ dll that uses JNI to call the Java code.  A bit funky, but it's actually worked pretty well.  However, I'm moving to a new dev box, and I've just run into a serious problem with this.  The built VB app works fine on the new box, but when I try to run it from VB, the dll fails to load the VM, getting a return code of -4 (JNI_ENOMEM) from JNI_CreateJavaVM.

Both the built app and VB are calling the exact same dll, and I've tried it with both Java 1.5 and 1.6.  I've tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798876/how-do-i-get-an-error-message-when-failing-to-load-a-jvm-via-jni) (redirecting stdout and stderr to files, adding a vfprint option, adding an -Xcheck:jni option), but to no avail.  I can't seem to get any additional information out of the jvm.  As far as I can tell, the new box is configured pretty much the same as the old one (installed software, Path, Classpath, etc.), and both are running the same release of Windows Server 2003.  The new machine is an x64 box with more memory (4GB rather than 2GB), but it's running 32-bit Windows.

Any suggestions or ideas about what else to look into?  Rewriting the whole thing in a more sane way is not an option -- I need to find a way to have the dll get the jvm to load without thinking that it's out of memory.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing any options to the JVM for setting the max heap and/or max perm size? The sum of those two sizes need to be available as a contiguous block for the JVM to start.

Comment: Originally, we were just using the defaults (just passing a class path).  I tried passing in various values for -Xmx and -Xms.  Up to 52m, the dll call just caused VB to quit (with no error messages).  From 53m up, I get the JNI_ENOMEM return code.  There's certainly plenty of memory available, and unless VB is doing something really odd with memory allocation for dlls, there should be enough contiguous memory available for a JVM with a 53MB heap.  And this all works just fine on my old dev box (and on all the other machines we've used this on).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've figured it out.  As kschneid points out, the JVM needs a pretty large contiguous chunk of memory inside the application's memory space.  So I used the sysinternals VMMap utility to see what VB's memory looked like.  There was, in fact, no large chunk of memory available, and there were some libraries belonging to Visio that were loadeed in locations that seemed to be designed to fragment memory.  It turns out that when I installed Visio on the new machine, it automatically installed the Visio UML add-in into VB.  Since I don't use this add-in, I disabled it.  With the add-in disabled, there was a large contiguous chunk of free memory available, and now the JVM loads just fine.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - I found the following extremely useful article: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6463655

I'm going to repeat some insanely useful code here because I'm not sure that I trust Oracle to keep the above forum around.

When I set up my JVM, I use a call to getMaxHeapAvailable(), then set my heap space accordingly (-Xmxm) - works great for workstations with less RAM available, without having to penalize users with large amounts of RAM.

```
bool canAllocate(DWORD bytes)
{
    LPVOID lpvBase;

    lpvBase = VirtualAlloc(NULL, bytes, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (lpvBase == NULL) return false;

    VirtualFree(lpvBase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return true;
}

int getMaxHeapAvailable(int permGenMB, int maxHeapMB)
{
    DWORD       originalMaxHeapBytes = 0;
    DWORD       maxHeapBytes = 0;
    int         numMemChunks = 0;
    SYSTEM_INFO     sSysInfo;
    DWORD       maxPermBytes = permGenMB * NUM_BYTES_PER_MB;     // Perm space is in addition to the heap size
    DWORD       numBytesNeeded = 0;

    GetSystemInfo(&sSysInfo);

    // jvm aligns as follows: 
    // quoted from size_t GenCollectorPolicy::compute_max_alignment() of jdk 7 hotspot code:
    //      The card marking array and the offset arrays for old generations are
    //      committed in os pages as well. Make sure they are entirely full (to
    //      avoid partial page problems), e.g. if 512 bytes heap corresponds to 1
    //      byte entry and the os page size is 4096, the maximum heap size should
    //      be 512*4096 = 2MB aligned.

    // card_size computation from CardTableModRefBS::SomePublicConstants of jdk 7 hotspot code
    int card_shift  = 9;
    int card_size   = 1 << card_shift;

    DWORD alignmentBytes = sSysInfo.dwPageSize * card_size;

    maxHeapBytes = maxHeapMB * NUM_BYTES_PER_MB;

    // make it fit in the alignment structure
    maxHeapBytes = maxHeapBytes + (maxHeapBytes % alignmentBytes);
    numMemChunks = maxHeapBytes / alignmentBytes;
    originalMaxHeapBytes = maxHeapBytes;

    // loop and decrement requested amount by one chunk
    // until the available amount is found
    numBytesNeeded = maxHeapBytes + maxPermBytes; 
    while (!canAllocate(numBytesNeeded + 50*NUM_BYTES_PER_MB) && numMemChunks > 0) // 50 is an overhead fudge factory per https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6463655 (they had 28, I'm bumping it 'just in case')
    {
        numMemChunks --;
        maxHeapBytes = numMemChunks * alignmentBytes;
        numBytesNeeded = maxHeapBytes + maxPermBytes;
    }

    if (numMemChunks == 0) return 0;

    // we can allocate the requested size, return it now
    if (maxHeapBytes == originalMaxHeapBytes) return maxHeapMB;

    // calculate the new MaxHeapSize in megabytes
    return maxHeapBytes / NUM_BYTES_PER_MB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem described by "the klaus" and read "http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126962".  Changed the registry as described in the mentioned article.  I exagerated my change to : "%SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=3072,3072,3072 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=basesrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=winsrv:ConServerDllInitialization,2 ProfileControl=Off MaxRequestThreads=16"

The field to look at is "SharedSection=3072,3072,3072".  It solved my problem, but I may have side-effects because of this change.

Comment: That doesn't really look like the same problem. The cause of the issue for this question is fragmented process address space, not running out of WIN32 desktop heap space.