# Redirecting input and output of a child process in C

Tags: c, process, file-descriptor, io-redirection, child-process

I want to write a c program in which i create multiple child processes and redirect their inputs and outputs to different file descriptors .I googled a lot but couldn't find relevant results. Please help .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c

Comment: @jweyrich your link is irrelevant to this question

Answer (score 3):

Start with [dup](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup).  You really need to search a bit harder.  There is plenty of material on this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your operating system. On UNIX-like systems, you use `dup()` and `dup2()` to copy file descriptors around; each child process will inherit the current set of file descriptors from the parent when it is `exec`-ed.  So typically you `fork` the child process, set file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 to whatever you want them to be, and then `exec()` the actual child program.

Comment: Since the phrase "file descriptors" was used, then I guess it must be UNIX/Linux.  For completeness: on Windows use CreateProcess and look at the last three members of the STARTUPINFO struct.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is [forkpty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty). This function forks a child and give you a file descriptor to its stdin/stdout. You can use exec after forking,