# redirecting standard output in c then resetting standard output

Tags: c, fcntl, unistd.h

I'm trying to use redirects in C to redirect input to one file and then set standard output back to print to the screen. Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //create file "test" if it doesn't exist and open for writing setting permissions to 777
    int file = open("test", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0777);
    //create another file handle for output
    int current_out = dup(1);

    printf("this will be printed to the screen\n");

    if(dup2(file, 1) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't redirect output\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("this will be printed to the file\n");

    if(dup2(current_out, file) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't reset output\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("and this will be printed to the screen again\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a completely different way to solve this same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `dup2` call is wrong, replace with:

```
if (dup2(current_out, 1) < 0) {
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing you'll have to make sure to do before that will work at all, is to call `fflush(stdout);` before switching the `stdout` file descriptor out from under it. What's probably happening is that the C standard library is buffering your output, unaware that you're shifting around the file descriptors underneath it. The data you write using `printf()` isn't *actually* sent to the underlying file descriptor until its buffer becomes full (or your program returns from `main`).

Insert the call like this:

```
    fflush(stdout);
    if(dup2(file, 1) < 0) {
```

before both calls to `dup2()`.

Comment: I don't think this was OP's problem here, but it's very good advice and should almost always be followed whenever you mix stdio with file descriptor io.

Comment: That's true, I actually didn't notice the incorrect file descriptor at first until somebody else mentioned it. When writing to a terminal, stdio output will probably be line buffered, so the code without `fflush()` is likely to work until the OP tries redirecting stdout to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `dup2(current_out, file)` with `dup2(current_out, 1)`, and things should work better.