# Redirect the stdout to buffer,not using >

Tags: c++, buffer, printf, stdout

I wrote my implementation of printf – myPrintf,which prints to stdout.
I want to verify that it works fine.In order to check the correctess of the printed output I want to compare it with char I expect to get. How can I write code to  redirect the stdout to buffer,not using >.

**I can use only printf!**

Comment: Why are you opposed to teeing the output to a file with `>`?

Comment: If this is C++ why not use iostreams instead? Then "capturing" the output is simply a question of using a `stringstream`

Comment: Without knowing what you are actually using to print it out, its hard to tell what to use to capture the output.

Comment: I have to redirect from stdout to char buffer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could redirect `couts` buffer by setting it's `rdbuf()` to a file you have opened.

Weird, C++ and only printf, but whatever.

It's also possible to redirect stdout in C.

Here is one way of doing it: https://rydow.wordpress.com/2007/10/26/c-code-to-redirect-stdout/

It involves `dup` and `dup2`.

There is also this option ( [Rerouting stdin and stdout from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c) ) using `freopen`.

Comment: Or to a custom `std::streambuf` that copies into some place in memory (think `std::ostringstream`).