# How to make a bash program accept commands from another C program

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'm new to linux and programming. I opened an application program from a C program using **system("Prog");**

```
Prog-> #after opening the program
```

This "Prog" accepts certain commands from user and displays output.

```
Prog-> write # Accepts the command from user
1 2 3 4 5    # Displays the output 
Prog->       # Waiting for next command
```

I want to make the command sent from a C program instead of getting it from the user. I can't use system(""); to send the commands to the opened program "Prog" (as in passing commands to CLI from C program). system(); works only for CLI and not to the opened program.

Is there any way that I can send the commands to opened application from a C program?

I should also store the displayed output "1 2 3 4 5" in a file. Pls help.

Comment: It will be easier with `fork` and `execv` than with `system`. Look up the man pages for `fork` and `execv` on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superficially, you might find the [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) function appropriate, along with the
[`pclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html) function.

```
FILE *fp = popen("Prog", "w");
```

This indicates that your program will write to `fp` to send data to the standard input of `Prog`.  The standard output of `Prog` will go to the same place as the standard output of your program.  When you're finished, you close the stream with `pclose()`:

```
pclose(fp);
```

If you need more control over where the output goes, you will need to use:

- [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
- [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)
- [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
- [`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html)

If this is insufficient — if `Prog` does not react well to not having a terminal for input and/or output — then you will need to investigate pseudo-ttys or `pty` devices.  These are a little tricky to use; they're a subject for a separate question (and there's probably several relevant questions with answer already available on SO to cover their use).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by redirecting with `fork()` and `exec()`, `execv()`, `execvp()`, etc. This creates a separate process, (and this is the standard way to do so, rather than with `system`), but it allows you to redirect the I/O of that process however you please, similar to how bash does it. Take a look:

http://publicabstractvoid.blogspot.com/2008/01/forkexec-while-redirecting-io.html

Take a look at the dup2(2) and fork(2) manpages.

Answer (score 0):

If your "Prog" reads the commands from the standard input, you can pipe commands from your C program to "Prog". Also, you can capture, in your C program, the text written by "Prog" to stdout and stderr streams. One example how to do that can be found here: [Linux 3.0: Executing child process with piped stdin/stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405985/linux-3-0-executing-child-process-with-piped-stdin-stdout)