# How can I enter continuously by another C++ program in C system / popen command?

Tags: c++, c, popen

### I want to build a compile system in an online judge system.

#### Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, g++ version 4.9

---

My workflow is "Compile cpp" -> "Execute it" -> "Record message".

But I got some problems when "the cpp file exist 'scanf' or 'cin' commands".

Because this is a auto-compile & run program, there is an other input need to load. (Is a string from function call not enter in terminal by myself)

---

### My problem

How can I run the `executeCommand` (below code in compiler.cpp), using the string `input` (below too) to enter for this program. If the executed program exist any `scanf`, `cin` or other commands.

---

## compiler.cpp

This is `system` command version, can replace to `popen` command too.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    // Compiler one cpp file.
    string compileCommand = "(g++ --std=c++11 ./main.cpp -o ./main.out) 2> main.err";
    system(compileCommand.c_str());

    // Execute this program.
    string executeCommand = "(time timeout -k1s 0.01s ./main.out) > result.txt 2> time.txt";
    system(executeCommand.c_str());

    // I want the above main.out will scanf from this string.
    string input = "Hello world, this is first line.\nThis is second line.";

    return 0;
}
```

---

## main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char str[256];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry my basic English, I enhance my description now.

Comment: What happens if someone submits a program which deletes all your files?

Comment: @AlanStokes, sounds terrible... I don't have any idea on this issue, can you give me some advice?

Comment: I think you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405985/linux-3-0-executing-child-process-with-piped-stdin-stdout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (and you flagged your question as such).

```
FILE*pcmd = popen("time ./main.out", "w");
if (!pcmd) { perror("popen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
fprintf(pcmd, "Hello world, this is first line.\n");
fprintf(pcmd, "This is the second line.\n");
fflush(pcmd);
int bad = pclose(pcmd);
if (bad) {fprintf(stderr, "pclose failed %d\n", bad); };
```

Be aware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) issues, in particular when passing a computed command to `popen` or `system`

You might need some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Then use `fork`, `execve`, `pipe` and other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) explicitly, so read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a pipe, system( "echo YOUR_STRING | ./main.out " )