# Deadlock when communicating with child process with redirected I/O

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork, dup2

I am writing a program to communicate with the SPIN model checker's interactive module programatically. For this, I need to redirect SPIN's I/O, launch it from my program, and then repetitively read from and write to it. For testing, I am using, instead of spin, the following short program with only one input and one output:

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

void sprint(string s);
int main() 
{   
    std::string s = "empty";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "\n\tthe text is: " << s;
    return 0;    
}
```

My program, taken mostly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405985/linux-3-0-executing-child-process-with-piped-stdin-stdout/12839498), is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PIPE_READ 0
#define PIPE_WRITE 1
#define maxReadSize 2048
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int createChild(const char* szCommand, const char* aArguments, const char* szMessage);

int main()
{
    createChild("./inout" , "inout", "hello");
    return 0;
}


int createChild(const char* szCommand, const char* aArguments, const char* szMessage) 
{
    int cStdinPipe[2];
    int cStdoutPipe[2];
    int nChild;
    char nChar;
    int nResult;

    if (pipe(cStdinPipe) < 0) 
    { 
        return -1;
    }
    if (pipe(cStdoutPipe) < 0) 
    {
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_READ]);
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_WRITE]);
        return -1;
    }

    nChild = fork();
    if (0 == nChild) 
    {
        // child continues here
        cout.flush();
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_WRITE]);

        // redirect stdin
        if (dup2(cStdinPipe[PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) 
        {
            exit(errno);
        }

        // redirect stdout
        if (dup2(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) 
        {
            exit(errno);
        }

        // all these are for use by parent only
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_READ]);
        close(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_READ]);
        close(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_WRITE]); 

        // run child process image
        nResult = execlp(szCommand, aArguments, NULL);

        // if we get here at all, an error occurred, but we are in the child
        // process, so just exit
        exit(nResult);
    } 
    else if (nChild > 0) 
    {
        // parent continues here
        string messageFromChild = "";
        string messageFromParent = "";
        char readBuffer[maxReadSize];
        int bytesWritten = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        // close unused file descriptors, these are for child only
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_READ]);
        close(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_WRITE]); 

        // write to child
        if (NULL != szMessage) 
        {
            bytesWritten = write(cStdinPipe[PIPE_WRITE], szMessage, strlen(szMessage));
        }

        // read from child
        bytesRead = read(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_READ], readBuffer, maxReadSize);

        cout << "\nChild says: " << readBuffer << "\n";

        // done with these in this example program, you would normally keep these
        // open of course as long as you want to talk to the child
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_WRITE]);
        close(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_READ]);

        std::cout << "\n\nParent ending";
    } 
    else 
    {
        // failed to create child
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_READ]);
        close(cStdinPipe[PIPE_WRITE]);
        close(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_READ]);
        close(cStdoutPipe[PIPE_WRITE]);
    }
    return nChild;
}
```

Running this program results in a deadlock where the child is stuck on `cin` and the parent on `read()`. Removing either of these calls causes both programs to run to termination and exit normally. `write()` and `cout` both work properly.

Comment: You might be able to fix it by using `poll()` or `select()` in at least one of the processes, so you can know whether reading or writing is possible before you attempt it.

Comment: Now it gets stuck on the `select()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with how `read()` and `write()` work on various streams/files/pipes. My `write()` could not communicate to the `read()` that it had finished writing. `Read()` was relying on `EOF` which was only sent after the write end of the pipe was closed. Ofcourse, once it was closed, it was gone forever and I could not reopen it to send another message.

I therefore switched to named pipes ([`fifo`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/fifo)) so I could reopen the pipes after each write.