# Redirect stdin to pipe (popen) C++

Tags: c++, pipe, stdin

I hope that this is not a stupid question.  Is it possible to redirect stdin to a FILE?

```
FILE* somePipe = _popen("SOME_FILE", "r");
```

Can I assign somePipe to stdin?

Comment: Have you looked at `freopen`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `freopen()`:

```
 FILE* somePipe = freopen("SOME_FILE", "r", stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 FILE* inPipe   freopen("newstdin", "r", stdin);
 FILE* outPipe  freopen("newstdout", "w", stdout);
```