# How do I pass System.out from Java to C using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have C++ dll that runs a java program using JNI, and I'm trying to figure out how to capture the output of that java program. I've tried using a stringstream to redirect the stdout to a buffer, but this only seems to grab output coming from my dll. What can I do to read in System.out?

This is what I'm trying now, which doesn't work:

```
using namespace std;

stringstream buffer;
streambuf * old = cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());
//run java stuff here
```

After I do this, `buffer.str()` is still empty, even though the java methods execute properly and there are System.out.println() calls in those methods. If I do something like `cout << "test" << endl;`, the buffer.str() gets that text, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the buffer. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

By modifying `cout` buffer, you didn't modified the standard output stream, just the object that used to encapsulate it.

To completely redirect the output, you have to `freopen` `stdout` to a file or pipe, you can get more information in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c).

Then to get the complete output of the java code, you can open the same file (or pipe) in reading mode an simply get the information you want.

By the way, in your code example, you don't need the `stringstream` but just the associated `stringbuf` no?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this - only the stuff I print using printf() gets redirected to the file.

Comment: Then the JVM reopens the stdin... Interesting question, I'll try to think about that tomorrow again. I think you have to hack it first on the Java side