# Check the return value of freopen() in C

Tags: c, freopen

I'm aware that the right use of `freopen` is to omit the assignment, given this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586416):

`freopen("/dev/tty","r", stdin);`

My question is, should I still check the return value? I'm reopening stdin and closing whatever it was. For instance:

```
if(freopen("/dev/tty","r", stdin)==NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to redirect stdin from file\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Well... why do you think it returns a value?

Comment: I guess I don't know when and why it would return a null pointer.

Comment: that's why there is a manual page :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) for freopen says:

> If the file is successfully reopened, the function returns the pointer
>   passed as parameter "stream", which can be used to identify the reopened
>   stream. Otherwise, a null pointer is returned. On most library
>   implementations, the errno variable is also set to a system-specific
>   error code on failure.

So yes, you could check the return value against NULL to see if there's an error, or check errno.

Regarding your comment, the documentation says:

> If a new filename is specified, the function first attempts to close
>   any file already associated with stream (third parameter) and
>   disassociates it. Then, independently of whether that stream was
>   successfuly closed or not, freopen opens the file specified by
>   filename and associates it with the stream just as fopen would do
>   using the specified mode.

Based on "independently of whether that stream was successfuly closed or not", it seems possible that the original stream could be left open, or in an undefined state, if there's an error.  In any case, this won't make any practical difference, since you wouldn't want to use the stream after freopen fails anyway.

Comment: In which state is the original stream if an error is returned?

Comment: @Devolus i would guess anything but "happily open".

Comment: Awesome, I guess I should've checked the man page. One more question, it appears that if I check the return value, then when I redirect stdin and the output goes to a file, I get `No such device or address`. Do you know what could be the reason?