# JNA redirect STDOUT to JFrame

Tags: jframe, stdout, jna

I used JNA to call some C++ methods from Java. Everything works fine. This methods contain "cout" to print some things. My question is if it is possible to redirect these prints from C++ methods to a JFrame in Java. In Java methods it is quite easy but I don't know if it possible for methods called through JNA. Ok I know it is a quite strange question but I would like to know if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to redirect the `cout` stream to where Java can read it.  You might use a circular buffer with producer/consumer pointers, a callback to Java with the most recent data, or any other method common to inter-process communication.  It'll *probably* be easier to redirect the stream in native code to test, but there's no reason you couldn't translate that native code into JNA calls.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c for one method of redirecting `stdout`.  If you dump to a file, you can have Java read from the file.  JNA is perfectly capable of calling `freopen`.

Comment: You may need to play around to find the actual value of `stdout`; look at your system's `<stdio.h>` file for its definition.  On OSX, it's a global symbol called `__stdout` of type `FILE*`.  On other systems it's the address of an element within a global array of `FILE` structs.

Comment: Ok I see. Actually I was thinking the same you mention in comment no2. For me at least the thing when you use JNA is to have something common between C/C++ and Java. So Files are probably the most easy way to implement this. By the way thanks a lot for your suggestions and if you want post one as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to redirect the `cout` stream to where Java can read it. You might use a circular buffer with producer/consumer pointers, a callback to Java with the most recent data, or any other method common to inter-process communication. It'll *probably* be easier to redirect the stream in native code to test, but there's no reason you couldn't translate that native code into JNA calls.

See [Rerouting stdin and stdout from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c) for one method of redirecting `stdout`. If you dump to a file, you can have Java read from the file. JNA is perfectly capable of calling `freemen`.

You may need to look around to find the actual value of `stdout`; look at your system's `<stdio.h>` file for its definition. On OSX, it's a global symbol called `__stdout` of type `FILE*`. On other systems it's the address of an element within a global array of `FILE` structs.

Comment: Did anyone try this method, I used the `freopen` with JNA redirect it to a file, to get the stdout, I find `__acrt_iob_func` is used in windows and that's captured by JNA as well. However it doesn't work, printf still print everything to the screen.