# Writing commands for input/ouput file redirection in custom shell

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix

I am writing my own shell in C. It's fairly simple, but I want to implement three more commands. First being commands, with or without arguments, whose output is redirected to a file. Second being, a command, with or without arguments, whose output is appended to a file. Lastly, a command, with or without arguments, whose input is redirected from a file.

All of these commands can be implemented using  the syscalls `freopen()`, `dup()` and `dup2()`.

An example of the first command could be `ls -l > fileName.txt`.
This should take the output of the command and put it in `fileName.txt`.

An example of the second command could be `ls -l >> fileName.txt`.
This should take the output of the command and append it to whatever is in the file `fileName.txt`.

An example of the last command could be `bc < file`. This takes the output of the command and put it in the named file.

This shouldn't be too hard to implement, but for some reason I don't know how to do it and am having some serious trouble. Could someone help me out?

Comment: "<" ">" redirects the stdin stdout of an executable file. so parse the argument for filename, open it, redirect the stdin/stdout from/to the file. you can use ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c...also >> is append so you can decide at file open (fopen in mode a+) ref http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick to raw system calls. Forget `freopen()` and use `open()`. The stdio routines work with `FILE*` streams while the syscalls work with integer file descriptors. Mixing the two guarantees serious trouble. ;-)

Redirection goes in 4 steps

- `open()` file to redirect to/from, returns an `fd`
- `close()` file to redirect, 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout
- `dup(fd)` fd was returned by `open()` in the 1st step
- `close(fd)` you don't need it enymore

The trick is that `dup()` returns the lowest available integer for a new file descriptor. If you've just closed stdout `1`, it will return `1`, and suddenly your stdout is pointing to the previously opened file.

Comment: I'd suggest `dup2` instead of `dup` since it does exactly what you want in one atomic operation.

Comment: Yes. But the project is obviously about learning, so I'd actually suggest trying both. :-)