# How to test code that writes to stdout?

Tags: c, cunit

How to write a test in CUnit for a function that prints to *stdout*, to verify its output?

Example function to test:

```
void print()
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

Its unit test should somehow verify that "Hello world" was printed to the console:

```
void test_print()
{
    // how to assert?
}
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "test stdout?"

Comment: I just use printf to print something. And I want to assert it's output.

Comment: Or write your own print function that returns something you can assert, or writes to a log.

Comment: @jpw Are you sure it's -1 specifically? The [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) just says a "negative value".

Comment: Then check for a negative value in the assert.

Comment: What. Are. You. Asserting?  What condition do you want to check for?

Comment: Redirect `stdout` before calling the tested function, and sort through its output afterwards. How to register PASS or FAIL is shown in the page @RobertHarvey linked.

Comment: @jpw: Return value of printf is about as useless as it can be. The assertion needs to check the _content_ of what was printed. Obviously not in contrived example, but in real use sure.

Comment: I'm learnning to use cuint.And write a list.Then append(...) and print list element to assert append wether succeed。

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I disagree with closure. The question is perfectly clear. Though from the last comment it appears to be asking wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @JanHudec: Since you seem to clearly understand the OP's problem, why don't you edit the question so that it clearly states what he wants to accomplish?  You had at least 6 minutes to write an answer; why didn't you write one?

Comment: @qianchenglong: Well, if you want to check that the correct elements were appended it is **much** easier to check content of the list afterwards. Or some auxiliary debug list or something. Checking output of `printf` is **difficult**.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Because 1) the question was already edited meanwhile and 2) the answer is actually _pretty difficult_.

Comment: The answer is to write your own proxy print function for printf.  The phrase "Assert printf" is meaningless.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Absolutely not. Horrible idea, much too intrusive, error-prone and difficult.

Comment: But sometime really to assert `stdout`.So I want to known how...

Comment: ***There is no `assert stdout.`***  That phrase doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's pretty clear what asserting stdout means, though it can be mis-understood when being too literal (not a good idea for any human language). Anyway, my edit to the question should have clarified it enough.

Comment: In other words.In some code, need to check stdout, how to do?

Comment: Redirect stdout to a file, and check the file.

Comment: Ok.If in cuint has no such api or some easy methods to do this.So do it...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Now the question (Which was lon-gago clarified) was answered multiple times in the comments. If it was open, I'm sure there would be a proper answer too.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272612/how-to-assert-a-bad-question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This ought to achieve what you're looking for.
(ie. how to tell that something was written to `stdout`)

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

void print()
{
    printf("Hello world");
}

void test_print()
{
    struct stat st;
    int bytesWritten = 0;

    // Redirect stdout
    freopen("redir.txt", "w", stdout)

    print();

    // assert checking
    stat("redir.txt", &st);
    bytesWritten = st.st_size;

    CU_ASSERT( bytesWritten < 0 );
}
```

Note that this ruins your ability to restore `stdout`, but that's a [known problem](http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html)  In the link, they suggest a means to use a `FILE` pointer and use `fprintf()` instead of `printf()`

---

`stdout` redirect example borrowed from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen)

File Size checking borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238609/1345223)

And here's a [reference link from CUNIT](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/doc/writing_tests.html)

And this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584930/1345223) may provide another way of accessing `stdout` without trashing it via `freopen()`.  Or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586490/1345223) to revert the redirect.

---

Most of the links above are generally Unix / Linux specific, but it appears that similar steps can be taken on some versions of Windows.

[This Product Documentation page for Win XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) provides a few ways to redirect or duplicate `stdout` through the command line.

It's worth noting that the XP documentation page points out that the same file descriptor numbers (0, 1, 2) are used for `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` so `freopen()` should behave the same on Windows as it does on Unix / Linux.

Comment: You know, just closing `stdout` might be bad. Not sure how CUNIT outputs its results...

Comment: @Deduplicator - probably wouldn't be my first choice, but I don't know the constraints the OP is working under.  Some of the SO answers I linked to had good ways to restore it or duplicate it.  But I think those were closer to platform specific and didn't want to muddy my answer too much with them.

Comment: I wrote in windows.But I also use linux.So if there is an OS independent will be much better!

Comment: @qianchenglong: Isn't standard C already platform independent?