# Can I access stdin without keyboard?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, stdin

I have compiled the following code with gcc

```
int main() {

  int a = 0;

  fprintf( stdin, "%d", 123 );
  fscanf( stdin, "%d", &a );
  printf( "%d\n", a );

  return 0;
}
```

In my expectation, the program should executes straightly (i.e., the program never pause and wait for user input). But it still stop, and wait for my input.

I want to know what happen when I try to write something to stdin and how to modify this code and it can execute straightly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/584868/694576

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If there are circumstances where you want to use "123" instead of the input from stdin, you should write a function that simply returns "123" under those circumstances, or the value from stdin otherwise. Don't try to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

`stdin` is for input only, `stdout` is for output. (4566976's answer shows you what happens when you try to output to `stdin`) See for example the [glibc documentation on standard streams](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html#Standard-Streams)

(in short, writing to `stdin` makes no sense at all)

Answer (score 3):

If you print out the return value of `fprintf(stdin` you can see that the function call fails.

In the shell you can pipe something into the `stdin` of the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int a = 0, ret;

  printf("%d\n", ret = fprintf( stdin, "%d", 123 ));
  if (ret < 0) perror("fprintf");
  fscanf( stdin, "%d", &a );
  printf( "%d\n", a );

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ echo 123 | ./a.out
-1
fprintf: Bad file descriptor
123
$
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition of the `fprintf(stdin,` [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32547595/841108) you also forgot that [`stdin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) is not the keyboard. The latest [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11) standard does not know about the keyboard. On a Linux graphical desktop, only the [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server is reading from the physical keyboard.

Practically speaking, on [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems notably such as Linux, `stdin` can be a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (using [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) in your shell is very common), a [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), a [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), a plain file (thru [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)) or even [`/dev/null`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html), and of course also a [*terminal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal).

The funny thing these days is that terminals are very often virtual emulated devices (I did not see any *real physical* terminal in this century, outside of museums), read about [pseudotty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal). The details are quite arcane for historical reasons. Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. See also [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) wikipage & [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) and [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) (so consider `/dev/tty` and perhaps `/dev/console`)

You can check (with [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)) that *stdin* is a terminal (actually a pseudotty) using `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)`...

Practically speaking, when you really want to use the terminal, I strongly recommend using a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (both are using [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html))

Don't forget that I/O is generally [buffered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), and use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) wisely.

BTW, you should have compiled with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then use the `gdb` debugger. And [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) would have been very useful too.

Maybe you wanted to pipe to your own program (but that is weird, and often wrong, unless you take great care about all the implications; it is however a very useful trick for handling [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) in event oriented programs, notably those with some [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)). Beware that pipes have a limited buffer size (so avoid [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), probably by having your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)) and read about `PIPE_BUF` and [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html). You might have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  int pfd[2] = {-1,-1};
  int a= 0;
  if (pipe(pfd)) { perror("pipe"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (dup2(pfd[0],STDIN_FILENO)<0)
      { perror("dup2 stdin"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
  if (dup2(pfd[1],STDOUT_FILENO)<0) 
      { perror("dup2 stdout"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
  if (printf("%d\n", 123)<=0) { perror("printf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (fflush(stdout)) { perror("fflush"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (scanf("%d", &a)<1) { perror("scanf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (a != 123) { fprintf(stderr, "impossible happened a=%d\n", a); };
  fprintf(stderr, "done...got a=%d\n", a);
}
```

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn more about [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html); it has several chapters related to this. Read carefully [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) and be aware that the above program would be wrong for a larger output (bigger that `PIPE_BUF`, which on my system is several kilobytes)

BTW, you can get a readable `FILE*` from a memory buffer using [fmemopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html). For writing (e.g. with `fprintf`) to an output buffer, consider `open_memstream` and don't forget to `fflush` it before accessing the output buffer.

Comment: "Thanks a lot Basile!! I would try to study what you write in your answer. My current subject is binary translation and I believe that it will be helpful for me : )"

Answer (score 2):

You can `ungetc()` a few characters and then read them with `fscanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int value = 0;

    ungetc ( '\n', stdin);//reverse order. newline first here but last from fscanf 
    ungetc ( '3', stdin);
    ungetc ( '2', stdin);
    ungetc ( '1', stdin);
    fscanf ( stdin, "%d", &value);
    printf ( "value is %d\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

output: value is 123

Comment: Thanks. It is a tricky method but it works in my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply incorrect thinking that `fscanf(stdin, "format", ...);` does not block and wait for input, because it does.