I use 'fprintf' write something to stdin, but 'scanf' couldn't read it
this is my code:
int i,j;
    
fprintf(stdin,"100 1010");
printf("%s\n",stdin); 
scanf("%d%d",&i,&j);
printf("%s\n",stdin); 

I trying write two numbers to stdin,then I want scanf to accept these parameters,but when the program ran, I still had to input something, and scanf didn't seem to read anything directly from stdin.
When I print stdin's content, both times it appears garbled.
I have a guess that the above code that uses fprintf to write something to stdin is invalid.
Is this the case? And I'm curious what exactly is stdin? How does stdin put what I type on the keyboard into its input buffer?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547384/can-i-access-stdin-without-keyboard

Maybe you want sscanf() ("string scan formatted") ie char t[] = "2024 3.14159"; if (sscanf(t, "%d%lf", &i, &x) != 2) /*error*/;

Some people say that stdin is bound to the keyboard, but how is stdin bound to the keyboard? I very want to know what the details are.

What is printf("%s\n",stdin); intended to do? The %s expects a string pointer, not a stream.

Note that fprintf(stdin,"100 1010"); returns -1 meaning it failed. Also, stdin is not bound to the keyboard, it can be redirected to read from a file.

"what exactly is stdin? How does stdin put what I type on the keyboard into its input buffer?" is quite broad.  Consider a narrower question.

Some people say that stdin is bound to the keyboard, but how is stdin bound to the keyboard? I very want to know what the details are. - That's easy: stdin has nothing to do with the keyboard.

I think you are misunderstanding what stdin is. It is a FILE*, so writing it as if it were a string is undefined behavior (you do this in your printf calls). Please see What exactly is stdin? for more details. I'm having difficulty finding a good reference (here is a questionable one), but I think stdin may be opened only for reading, so I'm not sure your code can be expected to work in general.
Also, you are missing a space betwen your %ds in your scanf.
I do agree, with the commenter, though. You may just want sscanf. Or possibly shell redirection (redirect a file to be stdin rather than interactive input).

The other issue is that you can't write to stdin, because it's opened in readonly mode.

@Sir Nate, "you are missing a space betwen your %ds in your scanf." --> No.  The space is not needed.  "%d" consumes leading whitespace already.  Note: Failing to check the return value of scanf() is another issue.

@Ray The C standard does not specify that stdin is in read-only mode, only that it's the "standard" "input" stream: "         stderr
stdin
stdout
which are expressions of type ''pointer to FILE'' that point to the FILE objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams."  Although expecting to be able to write to and then read from stdin is quite a stretch.

"missing a space betwen your %ds in your scanf" ... not really, no

I was basing the space on this, which says nothing, as far as I can tell, about consuming any whitespace with the format specifier.


I trying write two numbers to stdin, then I want scanf to accept these parameters, but when the program ran ...

To have stdin read from somewhere else, research freopen() so scanf() will read from the file.
// Open a file for writing (`fopen()`) and write (fprint()`) "100 1010".
// Close the file (`fclose()`)

// Reopen `stdin`  (`freopen()`).

// Read using `scanf()`, check `scanf()` return value.

