# How to make printf function print the output on a file instead of console?

Tags: c, file-io

We need to make the `printf` function write output on a file instead of console without involving any other function like `fprintf` etc.

As I understand, 1st half of the solution would be to close the console output file pointer so that `printf` is disabled to write any thing on console.

What next needs to be done (in C not C++)  to force `printf` to print output on file ?

Had this been C++, would function overriding solve this purpose ?

Comment: googling gets this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c

Comment: _"Had this been CPP, would function overriding solve this purpose ?"_ No, not really, you would need to specify a different function signature to override (more precise overload) `printf()`.

Comment: `printf` prints to standard output, which may or may not be the console. Under any reasonable OS, you can run a program with its output redirected to a file: `program_name > output_file.txt`. Aside from that, why can't you use `fprintf`?

Answer (score 1):

For C code, you could use the `freopen` function to associate `stdout` with the output file:

```
if ( freopen( "output.txt", "w", stdout ))
{
  printf( "this should go to the output file\n" );
}
else
{
  // could not associate stdout with the output file
}
```

Comment: `freopen("output.txt","a",stdout)` would be a better choice as this won't overwrite the contents(if any) in the file.

Answer (score 0):

First close stdout, then use `dup2()`:

```
int fd = open("filename", O_WRONLY);
....
close(1);
dup2(fd, 1);
```

From the man page:

> After  a  successful  return from dup() or dup2(), the old and new
>   file    descriptors may be used interchangeably.  They refer to the 
>   same  open    file description (see open(2)) and thus share file
>   offset and file sta-    tus flags; for example,  if  the  file  offset
>   is  modified  by  using    lseek(2)  on one of the descriptors, the
>   offset is also changed for the    other.

Comment: If you open a file with `O_RDONLY` flag you won't be able to write (print) anything in it.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Thanks.  Fixed.