# How to redirect program output to text file

Tags: c, linux, file

I want to redirect the output of a program to a file. How can I do this? At the moment my file doesn't get created, I can only print the output to my console.

```
    int fd[2];
    int processId;
    int output;
    char filename[] = "output.txt";

    if((output = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create/open file '%s'\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    if(pipe(fd) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if((processId = fork()) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error forking\n");
        return 3;
    }   

    if(processId == 0){
        int newFD = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
        char newFileDescriptor[2];
        sprintf(newFileDescriptor, "%d", newFD);
        dup2(fd[1], output);
        close(fd[0]);
        execl("./pipetest", "pipetest", newFileDescriptor, NULL);
    }else{
        close(fd[1]);
        char c[10];
        int r = read(fd[0], c, sizeof(char) * 10);

        if(r > 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "PIPE INPUT = %s", c);
            fwrite(c, 1, sizeof(c), output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can either redirect simply using `bash`, or you could use `freopen` to redirect `stdout` inside your program.

Comment: The most glaring issue is you using `100` as your buffer to `fwrite` (the only correct parameter in that call seems to be the `1`). Is there a reason why you're trying to do this with pipes instead of opening the file as fd 1 like a shell would?

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake, but also using this, it does not write to file. It is a task to use pipes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good start is not ignoring compiler warnings:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:42:13: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘fwrite’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
             fwrite(c, 1, sizeof(c), output);
             ^
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:715:15: note: expected ‘struct FILE * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern size_t fwrite (const void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
               ^
```

`int` and `FILE*` are not interchangable. If you use `open`, write with `write`. If you use `fopen`, write with `fwrite`.

Additionally, you never modify stdout of your process. Instead you modify `output`, which doesn't make sense. Here are the minimum changes to your code to make it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#include <fcntl.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    int fd[2];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    int processId;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    int output;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    char filename[] = "output.txt";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    if((output = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create/open file '%s'\n", filename);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    if(pipe(fd) == -1){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        return 2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    if((processId = fork()) == -1){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        fprintf(stderr, "Error forking\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        return 3;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    if(processId == 0){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        int newFD = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        char newFileDescriptor[2];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        sprintf(newFileDescriptor, "%d", newFD);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // You want to modify STDOUT_FILENO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        close(fd[0]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        execl("/bin/echo", "echo", newFileDescriptor, NULL); // switched to echo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }else{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        close(fd[1]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        char c[10];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        int r = read(fd[0], c, sizeof(char) * 10);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        if(r > 0){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            fprintf(stderr, "PIPE INPUT = %s", c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            write(output, c, r); // use write instead of fwrite                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Here's the result of running it:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
PIPE INPUT = 6
$ cat output.txt 
6
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do this at the bash by calling:

```
./myprogram > output.txt
```

This will redirect all of the outputs to output.txt

Comment: I'm creating a program that should do what the ">" does. Not use it.

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c

Comment: @OlarAndrei, it sounds like what your want is simply to write all of your output routines with `fprintf (fp, "....");` Then in your code, if you read `>` (or `>>`) as input, use `fopen` or `freopen` with the appropriate `mode` and take the file name as the next input following `>` or `>>`. (or `stdout` by default).

Comment: `./pipetest` has  two `printf()` which I want to redirect to a file and not to my stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `freopen`, it's probably the simplest way:

```
if (!freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout))
{
    // failed to open the file stream, handle the error
}
```

You can then just use `printf` to write to that file. You can do the same with `stderr`, but that's probably a bad idea - by definition `stderr` is used to report errors, and from what I know the convention is to have it output to console.

Answer (score 0):

Here's simples example how to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int out = open("/tmp/output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (out == -1) {
        perror("open:");
        return -1;
    }
    int r;
    r = close(1); /* this closes stdout */
    if (r != 0) {
        perror("close:");
        return -1;
    }
    r = dup2(out, 1); /* this duplicates your file descriptor to stdout */
    if (r == -1) {
        perror("dup2:");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("this should go to the output file\n");
    return 0;
}
```