# In Swift how can I capture standard out and standard error written to by C-function?

Tags: c, swift, redirectstandardoutput, bridging-header

I am using functions written in C with the help of a bridging header in my swift application. The code I am bridging writes to standard out and standard error, which shows up in the console in Xcode. Is there a way to capture that output from within my swift application?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c ?