# Redirect C stdin to read from C++ stringstream

Tags: c++, c, stdin, getchar, istringstream

I have some code that was provided to me written in C that I'm using in a C++ project. I need to add some functionality, along with unit tests. Unfortunately it's hard coded to use `getchar` and other C IO functions in a way that isn't very easy to test.

What I'm trying to do is mock the C `stdin`. Is there some way to create a C++ `stringstream` and redirect C `stdin` to read from that?

I know how to do it with `std::cin` but not `stdin`.

Comment: I would bite the bullet and spend some time to rewrite the C code into proper C++ code. Although I can think of some ugly hacks to accomplish this, I cannot chance the risk that this code, with my name on it, would eventually find its way to become a feature article on http://thedailywtf.com

Comment: Compile C as C, not C++! They are different languages.

Comment: Take a look at `freopen`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c however AFAIK you can only re-open `stdin` to a `FILE` source - you could hack it with a platform-specific technique that creates a 'virtual' file that corresponds to your `stringstream` but performance would suck because it would leave your program.

Comment: Another option might be to `#define getchar`, if you dare...

Comment: From the same process?  Tricky.  From the parent process it's trivial.  Just redirect stdin when you launch the process.  No muss no fuss.  If it's feasible to put your mocking harness in a different process, do that and don't worry about trying to hack the standard library.

Comment: It's for a school project, so I don't want to pour too much time into it. There's an autograder and some provided integration tests so if adding unit tests is too much trouble I'll just skip it. Currently I'm just adding a text file for each test and using freopen. Any pitfalls there?

Comment: What about opening a named pipe with freopen and writing to that from my tests?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/ if not maybe associating a streambuf*.

Comment: Why a named pipe?  You should just be able to use `pipe()` (assuming a POSIX environment).  If you're going to write more than the atomic write size (usually 4096 bytes), you may want to fork the writing end, and have it exit when finished.

Comment: This question would be much clearer if it had a [mcve].