# C program fragment to demonstrate how the standard input of a process may be redirected away from the terminal keyboard to a file

Tags: c, stdin

I have a question: *How C program fragment to demonstrate how the standard input of a process may be redirected away from the terminal keyboard to a file.*

Am very new to C. I have given a lot of my time and tried until here. Not sure how to proceed further. Can someone please guide me on this?

```
#include <stdli.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int fd;
    char str[255];

    fd = open ("foo", O_WRONGLY | O_CREATE, 0766);

    if (fd==-1){
        perror("Error inopening the file ");
        exit(1);
    }
     printf("Enter a string: ");
     fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
     dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
     .......
     ...
     exit(0);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rerouting stdin and stdout from C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c)

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us specifically what you "don't get". We can't cover everything from scratch so you need to tell us what you don't understand.

Comment: How to use freopen in this question guys?